# Safari 12.0.3 download attribute not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, download, safari

In my web application I would like to be able to download CSV files client-side with Javascript. I have written the following script for this purpose.

```
$(".csvStartgeld").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: API_URL,
        data: {rwks: rwks},
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer 12335567876ae432acb4"
        },
        success: function(data) {
            const a = document.createElement('a');
            const evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
            evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            a.download = 'startgeld.csv';
            a.href = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(data);
            a.target ="_blank";
            a.dispatchEvent(evt);
        }
    });
});
```

According to caniuse.com (https://caniuse.com/#search=download), Safari > 10.1 supports the download attribute. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work because I can only download the file nameless (the file is called Unknown). Actually it should be called startgeld.csv.

Do I make an error in my download script? Can you help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does it not show the content at all? Mobile Safari has many limitations around the download part. Even `content-disposition attachment; filename=xyz.csv` also does not work well. What exactly happens when you click on the link?

Comment: Safari (12.0.3) in MacOS downloads a file with correct content but without file name. If I rename the file Unknown to Unknown.csv, it will be recognized as a correct CSV file and can be opened in calculation programs. Is there a way Safari can download a file with a filename?